# Add Link to PHP message

Tags: php, urls, html

This feels like a noob question and I can't find references out there on how to do it. But I am adding a custom message the the default WP Login Page.

I want to add a hyperlink (to a support page on the front end) inside the text. How do I go about doing that?

```
function mito_login_message( $message ) {
if ( empty($message) ){
    return "<p>To log in, please use the same email address you used to confirm your participation in this virtual meeting. The password for the event can be found in the reminder emails you have received from the MITO Events Team over the past few days.</p>";
} else {
    return $message;
}
```

}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'mito_login_message' );

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in your function.php file

```
 function mito_login_message( $message ) {
        if ( empty($message) ){
            return "<p><a href=''>hyperlink</a>  Please login to continue</strong></p>";
        } else {
            return $message;
        }
    }

add_filter( 'login_message', 'mito_login_message' );
```